# Can a Serialized PHP Object be formatted for easy readability?

Tags: php, serialization, formatting, pretty-print, readability

PHP's Serializer produces a byte array which can be displayed as a single-line string via `var_dump()`.  The format of this string is very difficult to read, especially for scenarios such as objects stored in a database.

For the sake of reading these values is it possible to convert these to an indented, formatted readable string?  Or is the only option to retrieve them in PHP, `unserialize()` then, and then do something such as `var_dump()`?

Comment: serialized data is just a string,. you can format it anyway you want. but why format a serialized string? it's easier to format the original data structure

Comment: @MarcB is it a "true" string?  I'd thought the null bytes made it a bit dangerous to treat as such

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a great 1 liner:

```
<?php echo "<pre>" . print_r(unserialize($yourvar), 1) . "</pre>"; ?>
```

Comment: No prob! If that got it done for ya, mark answered :)